# Scrub/clear Last-Modified Date of File

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone know how, with VB.NET, to *clear* the last-modified date from a file's properties?  I looked through a lot of suggestions/examples on Google, but the focus was always on how to change the last-modified date.  What I want to do is to scrub (completely clear) the "Date Modified" of any file (this is a somewhat common practice in the legal industry).

Comment: Lies, lies, lies.  You'd better watch out, this could get you into enormous trouble in the USA.  There is no notion of "never modified", you could only set it back to FileInfo.CreationTime

Comment: Why don't you just set it to some value that is ridiculously obvious is fake?  e.g. 1/1/9999.

Comment: Thanks roryap and Hans Passan, I had both of those two suggestions, but when the attorney wants the file to be scrubbed, they want all of titles, comments, author, last modified by, etc... out of the file.  In this scenario, it's not so much of changing the metadata, but rather erasing it so that the recipient would not have certain info embedded to the file.  On the legal side, that's beyond my interest/control

Answer (score 2):

A file that has never been modified has a modified date that equals the creation date.

```
IO.File.SetLastWriteTime(sFile, IO.File.GetCreationTime(sFile))
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I was hoping to simply clear the last mod date rather than changing the date to something else.  I have seen third-party application that clear those file attributes completely or at least for those attributes that make sense anyway so there must be a way somehow.

Comment: Some of the stuff you mentioned in another comment are attributes that can be "Cleared" but not the modified date.  Windows will see it as a currput file and not allow you to work with the file any longer. BTW, this task you have will not be fun if you need to do the same to ms word/excel files. While the file (windows OS) has it's own attributes, so does office.